# change image source on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change image source in innerHtml data when the submit button is clicked.

```
<div id="areaEditor">
    <div class="holder">
        <img src="blob.blob"/>
        <input class="filesss" type="file" value="one.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
        <img src="blob.blob"/>
        <input class="filesss" type="file" value="two.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="holder">
        <img src="blob.blob"/>
        <input class="filesss" type="file" value="three.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>


$('#newsButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("klik");

    var source = $(".holder").find(".filesss").val();
    var imageTag = $(".holder").find("img").attr("src",source);
    var htmlData = $("#areaEditor").html();

    alert(htmlData);

})
```

However, the htmlData I alert there only shows me that the img src for the all three image tags is one.jpg.

How to make it corrects so  that the image src is based on each the closest input file there?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many `.holder` elements, you should loop them and get the `.filesss` value for each one and replace the image src as follows:

```
$('#newsButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("klik");

    $(".holder").each(function() {
        var source = $(this).find(".filesss").val();
        $(this).find("img").attr("src", source);
    });

    var htmlData = $("#areaEditor").html();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should have tried that before asking. :D

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to loop over the elements so it can take a single value each time, in your case; you are telling JQuery to get the source from the class `holder` which it finds it in the first element, so it does not need to look for anything else.

So you can do something like:

```
    <div id="areaEditor">
        <div class="holder">
            <img src="blob.blob"/>
            <input class="filesss" type="file" value="one.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div class="holder">
            <img src="blob.blob"/>
            <input class="filesss" type="file" value="two.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div class="holder">
            <img src="blob.blob"/>
            <input class="filesss" type="file" value="three.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script>  
    $('#newsButton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("klik");

        $(".holder").each(function() {
            var source = $(this).find(".filesss").val();
            $(this).find("img").attr("src",source);
        });

        var htmlData = $("#areaEditor").html();
        alert(htmlData);
    })
</script>
```